# Get MongoDB to use covered query for distinct()

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to use the distinct() aggregation operator to be able to list all of the possible values for a field in an embedded document while also using some query conditions to limit it.

Specifically I have in each document a sub-document which has source information.

```
"dataSource" : {
    "customer" : "Contoso"
    "site" : "Washington"
    "machine" : "Model A"
    "date" : "2015-02-18T16:48:00Z"
}
```

---

```
"dataSource" : {
    "customer" : "Umbrella"
    "site" : "Racoon City"
    "machine" : "Model A"
    "date" : "2015-02-18T16:48:00Z"
}
```

---

```
"dataSource" : {
    "customer" : "Contoso"
    "site" : "Mars"
    "machine" : "Model B"
    "date" : "2015-02-18T16:48:00Z"
}
```

I have a compound index set up on the data as well, and would like to be able to quickly run queries where I can retrieve all of the customers, select one, query for all sites which that customer owns, select one, and then query to list all of the machines which that customer has at that site.

Using distinct() I'm able to do this, but not very quickly as it has to run an IXSCAN as opposed to a covered query, so, is there any way to speed this up?

**Notes**
Other information which may or may not be relevant

- I'm using the C# driver and trying to incorporate this into a UI which I'm building, but I'm not even able to get it to work in the mongo shell
- Open to suggestions about how to restructure my data or approach, preferably if I could set up a way that the query (customer -> site -> machine) doesn't need to be strictly heirarchal
- I know that if a query returns the _id field, as shown [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_covered_queries.htm), it can't be a covered query, but I'm not sure how to use this to help me in my particular case
- It also appears that there are some [outstanding issues](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2104) but I'm not enough of an expert to tell if this is relevant, I'm indexing fields in embedded documents, not indexing the entire document itself.

**Edit: What I'm trying to do**
A full document would look something like this

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "createdBy": "aGenie",
    "MachineDetails": {
            "Name": "Model B - Line 12",
            "ServerID": "0",
            "TestResult": {
                "toolname": "Diagnostic Protocol 1",
                "camera" : "Side View 2"
                "pass": "false",
                "confidence": "1",
            },
        },
    "dataSource" : {
        "customer" : "Contoso"
        "site" : "Mars"
        "machine" : "Model B"
        "date" : "2015-02-18T16:48:00Z"
    },
}
```

I'm recording runtime data from the machine as a series of documents.  Each individual document represents a component being tested.  Depending on the length of the recording session this can generate anywhere from a few thousand documents to many more, with the goal being that new versions of the software can be tested by "playing back" this recorded data and comparing the results with the output the quality control process originally concluded.

All of these have the dataSource subdocument so that by running a distinct() query on dataSource.customer I can see all of the customers for which I have data, then by running a distinct(dataSource.site, { dataSource.customer : Contoso}) I can see all of the sites owned by that customer for which I have data...

Then once I've specified customer, site, machine, date I can find all of the documents which match, retrieve them, and then run a test which simulates the conditions at that particular machine for that particular day.

Comment: It's really not that clear here what the complete document structure looks like. Or are you saying the information you are displaying is your full document? If not then please list a whole document, or relevant surrounding parts to give an idea of structure. Also, what is the overall goal here? Is it just that you want the distinct "site" and "machine" value s for each "customer" you wish to look up?

Comment: I'd like to be able to quickly query for every distinct value of dataSource.customer, and then by knowing the customer be able to quickly query for every value we have stored of dataSource.site

While I can do this using either the distinct() wrapper or the C# driver I cannot get it to do so using only an index instead of the much slower scan.

Comment: I believe I may have discovered a workaround for my particular use-case, if it works out I'll rephrase the question and post the answer.

Although it does sidestep the original problem I'm going to pull the embedded document out and instead keep them in a different collection for indexing.